# Proving point lies on a line with Vector Geometry

Tags: geometry, vectors

[image]

[image]

I was doing the above question. Where m is the midpoint of OP. RG is also half the length of OP.

[image]

The answers on the marksheet are the above. I don't understand how this sufficiently proves that H is a point on MG. I understand the mathematics in the answer but I can't seem to understand why this proves the above statement.

Comment: You are given "$H$ is a point on $TQ$". You don't need to prove it. What you need to prove is $H$ is on $MG$. You can get this from the last equation on the left $\overline{MG}=2\overline{MH}$

Comment: @Andrei I'm slightly confused on how that proves H lies on MG.

Comment: If a vector is a constant times another vector, it means that the two vectors are parallel or collinear. So $MG||MH$. Since they have a point in common, it means that they are on the same line.